# FireBase Deeplink iOS API nil response

Tags: ios, firebase, dynamic-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I was trying to integrate FireBase deep linking on s sample iOS App the deep link is launching my app, whan am trying to parse the deep link am getting null response, am geeting dynamic link object as nil and error as nil.

here is my code

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void(^)(NSArray * __nullable restorableObjects))restorationHandler
  {

    if (userActivity.webpageURL) {

        NSLog(@"url exists");

        NSLog(@"web page url is %@", userActivity.webpageURL);

        BOOL handled = [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks]
                          handleUniversalLink:userActivity.webpageURL
                          completion:^(FIRDynamicLink * _Nullable dynamicLink,
                                       NSError * _Nullable error) {
                              if (error) {
                                  NSLog(@"error in link object is %@", error);

                              }
                              else{
                                  NSLog(@"dynamic link object is %@", dynamicLink);
                              }
                          }];

        return handled;
    }
    return NO;
  }
```

Comment: Any luck? I'm seeing the same problem.

Comment: @HeavenlyManBR just try with latest SDK it worked for me, even if it does work you call a GET request with the URL to get content. trying with the latest SDK resolved this issue for me.